# F# types and dynamic evaluation for basic computations

Tags: f#, functional-programming, logic, expression, expression-trees

Trying to get used to F# I tried small examples and my next step is to write a few functions for logical computations/evaluations and for now I have this structure

```
type Expr =
    | True
    | False
    | Not of Expr
    | And of Expr * Expr
```

and it should be obvious what I want to achieve: to be able to encapsulate different functions like `Not` and `And` to be used in one computation like `And(And(True, Not(False)), True)` but currently I do not understand (this is my first time wrinting such "complex" functional code) how to use this struct and write the proper methods as for example i can write for evaluation

```
let evalLogic (expr : Expr) : bool =
    match expr with
    | True  -> true
    | False -> false
    | _     -> false (* eval the expression which is not "atomic" *)
```

and then as a method

```
let And (left : Expr , right : Expr ) : Expr =
    let value = evalLogic(left) && evalLogic(right)
    match value with
    | true  -> True
    | false -> False
```

however I know that this is crap and not the correct way of implementing this! Can you give me a hint how to achieve the desired behavior and describe how to extend this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing functional code to represent and evaluate expressions, the typical pattern is to define the type of expression as a discriminated union (just like you did!) and then write a function that takes the expression and returns the result. Your logical expressions will evaluate to boolean, so you need a function:

```
evalLogic : Expr -> bool
```

In the function, you need to write a case for every possible expression. Your sample handles `False` and `True` and the code by Bluepixy shows the rest. The general idea is that the function can recursively evaluate all sub-expressions - if you have `And(e1, e2)`, then you can evaluate `e1` and `e2` to two boolean values and then combine them (using `&&`).

Your `And` function is not needed, because the whole evaluation is all done in the `evalLogic` function. This is a typical way of doing things in the functional style (because the expression type is not expected to change frequently). Howeever, you could also support more binary operations using:

```
type Expr = 
  | Constant of bool
  | Unary of Expr * (bool -> bool)
  | Binary of Expr * Expr * (bool -> bool -> bool)
```

Here, the idea is that an expression is either a constant or an application of some binary or unary logical operator. For example, to represent `true && not false`, you could write:

```
Binary(Constant(true), Unary(Constant(false), not), (&&))
```

Now the expression tree also carries the function that should be used, so the evaluation just needs to call the function (and you can use all standard logical operators easily). For example, the case for `Binary` looks like this:

```
let rec evalLogic e =
  // pattern matching
  |  Binary(e1, e2, op) -> op (evalLogic e1) (evalLogic e2)
```

Comment: +1 I got the feeling that functional coding is quite freaky and really painful at the beginning as I am coding C++ and C# for half a decade, however your explanation is fantastic and F# gets more and more interesting to me ;-) - Can you explain me further, whether there is a possibility **NOT** to eval a `Constant` until really needed, e.g. I am working with `True` and `False` and only on execution of something like `evalConst(e : Constant)` this one gets evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

```
let rec evalLogic (expr : Expr) : bool =
    match expr with
    | True  -> true
    | False -> false
    | Not (exp ) -> not (evalLogic exp)
    | And (expL, expR) -> evalLogic expL && evalLogic expR
```

**DEMO**

```
> evalLogic <| And(And(True, Not(False)), True);;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: This whole thing is my research on F# because I want to write small CAS components (someone told me to try functional programming languages) and I want to know, how can I build a better structure if I want to implement 100 functions for example. A really big matching pattern would be overkill in this case, eh?

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstand the meaning it is said that you are unsure. 
If you're considering some data structure 100 patterns, then it probably do I split function to split the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Is your question "how do I extend `evalLogic` for `Not` and `And`?"

If so, then you need to extend the pattern-matching in the let-expression to match the other two constructors:

```
let evalLogic (expr : Expr) : bool =
    match expr with
    | True  -> true
    | False -> false
    | Not (myexpr) -> ... (* match constructor `Not`, bind the expression to `myexpr`)
    | And (lefte, righte) -> ...
```

Then you can fill in the right-hand sides with some F# code.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) some information on pattern-matching in F#.